Дергаются элементы UIPickerView при анимации
Я делаю кастомный календарик для выбора недель, мне нужно сделать UIPickerView для выбора месяца и года. Он должен раскрываться и скрываться при нажатии кнопки. При раскрытии все хорошо и он анимируется плавно. При закрытии все его элементы дрегаются вверх хотя сам UIPickerView анимируется плавно. В Чем может быть проблема?
func picker(_ isShow: Bool){
    let currentHeight = isShow ? self.frame.height * 0.8 : 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.datePickerHeightConstraint.constant = currentHeight
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.datePicker.layoutSubviews()
    })
}

в этом коде:
datePickerHeightConstraint - констрейн с высотой пикера
datePicker - сам пикер

